# Does /revisions API return latest revisions?

Tags: dropbox-api

There is `/revisions` API described here https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#revisions.

> rev_limit Default is 10. Max is 1,000. When listing a file, the service won't report listings containing more than the amount specified and will instead respond with a 406 (Not Acceptable) status response.

Does it mean that if I will update file on my dropbox more than 1000 times then I wont be able to get any revision history of this file using DropBox Core API?

If there is a limit of 1000 revisions why this api wont just return LAST 1000 revisions instead of returning NOTHING when there is more than 1000 revisions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In actuality, this endpoint will returned the most recent *n* revisions, up to `rev_limit`. I'm updating the documentation to match.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was confusing.